# How to upgrade Hapi Fhir server on docker?

Tags: docker, upgrade, postgresql

I have a very old hapi fhir server and I want to upgrade it from 5.1.0 to 6.10.1-tomcat. I can't find the upgrade method on the internet. How can I upgrade hapi fhir?

I'm using hapi-fhir-cli migrate-database on PostgreSQL, but it only suggests tables. How do I move the old hapi fhir data into the new hapi fhir database?